# Binding control to class file MVVM WPF C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, hamburger-menu

I still learning about wpf and c# and i recently find out something like mvvm :)
I trying to rebuild my project to it but i stuck at binding control to .cs file

I've had hamburger menu from MahApps and something like

MainView.xaml

```
  <controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
                            IsPaneOpen="False"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}"
                            OptionsItemsSource="{Binding OptionsMenu}"
                            ItemInvoked="{Binding HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                            OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                            DisplayMode="CompactInline" />
```

I want to use HamburgerMenuControl in ViewModel Namespace how can i bind it to that MainViewModel.cs file

Thats my MainViewModel.cs

```
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MenuItem = MainViewModel.ViewModels.MenuItem;
using Prism.Mvvm;

using MainViewModel.ViewModels;

namespace MainViewModel.ViewModels
{
 public partial class MainViewModel: MetroWindow
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Navigation.Navigation.Frame = new Frame() { NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden };
        Navigation.Navigation.Frame.Navigated += SplitViewFrame_OnNavigated;
        this.Loaded += (sender, args) => Navigation.Navigation.Navigate(new Uri("Views/LogoView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    private void SplitViewFrame_OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.HamburgerMenuControl.Content = e.Content;
        this.HamburgerMenuControl.SelectedItem = e.ExtraData ?? ((ShellViewModel)this.DataContext).GetItem(e.Uri);
        this.HamburgerMenuControl.SelectedOptionsItem = e.ExtraData ?? ((ShellViewModel)this.DataContext).GetOptionsItem(e.Uri);
    }


    private void HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked(object sender, HamburgerMenuItemInvokedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = e.InvokedItem as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem != null && menuItem.IsNavigation)
        {
            Navigation.Navigation.Navigate(menuItem.NavigationDestination, menuItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried few tips from google but i still got error `'MainViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'HamburgerMenuControl' and no extension method 'HamburgerMenuControl' accepting a first argument of type 'MainViewModel'`

Do you have any advice? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is very bad practise to access your View (UI elements) from your ViewModel. The whole purpose of MVVM is to separate concerns. Here, check out this [MVVM tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

You should expose properties in your ViewModel and bind to it inside your View. In this instance, your ViewModel should contain the `Menu` and `MenuOptions` properties (I'm guessing as an `ObservableCollection<T>`).

Also, for your `MainViewModel` to be an actual ViewModel, it should not inherit `MetroWindow`, which is a UI component from MahApps. Your `MainWindow` however should probably inherit from `MetroWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

This is your binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}"
```

It will bind to a property called `Menu` inside your page binding (which you haven't posted), but it's the page that you should be binding to the View Model.

**TLDR**
@Sulli 's advice is correct, it does sort of negate the purpose of MVVM if you reverence the view from the view model or vice-versa.  Looking at what you're doing, you might find it better to put the code above in a code-behind module from your view.

Strictly speaking, communicating between view models is probably something you'd want to do using a messaging system.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will try it after lecture